# Installed new kernel on Ubuntu 12.04. How do I start it?

Tags: 12.04, grub2, kernel

I installed linux-image-3.12.24-031224-generic on Ubuntu 12.04 but cannot find a way to start it. 
uname -r still says 3.2.0-80-generic.

```
 $ dpkg -l | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-3.12.24-031224-generic     3.12.24-031224.201407041335                         Linux kernel image for version 3.12.24 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-23-generic           3.2.0-23.36                                         Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-80-generic           3.2.0-80.116                                        Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                    3.2.0.80.94                                         Generic Linux kernel image
```

When I select advanced options for 12.04 in GRUB during startup, it only lists the 3.2 kernels.

Am I missing a step?

@EricClemons ls /boot before and after sudo update-grub:

```
$ ls /boot
abi-3.12.24-031224-generic         initrd.img-3.2.0-80-generic
abi-3.2.0-23-generic               memtest86+.bin
abi-3.2.0-80-generic               memtest86+_multiboot.bin
config-3.12.24-031224-generic      System.map-3.12.24-031224-generic
config-3.2.0-23-generic            System.map-3.2.0-23-generic
config-3.2.0-80-generic            System.map-3.2.0-80-generic
grub                               vmlinuz-3.12.24-031224-generic
initrd.img-3.12.24-031224-generic  vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic
initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic        vmlinuz-3.2.0-80-generic
```

3.12.24 still does not show up though.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see your new image in the /boot directory?

```
$ ls /boot
```

It may be as simple as doing:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, I modified my question, no enough space here.